# What are the performance implications of drawable downscaling?

Tags: android, performance, android-resources

Is there a way of working out what, if any, performance implications are associated with allowing the Android OS to downscale images from the hdpi bucket for a mdpi device?

To give a use case - I'm shipping a fairly large, fairly complex application and to save space I've proposed to strip out mdpi assets and allow the OS to downscale from the hdpi drawables folder.  The worry is that this may have an impact on performance, which is noteworthy as the app is already quite resource hungry and mdpi devices aren't necessarily known for being high spec devices.

Comment: For `high spec devices` I'd use `xxhdpi` graphic resources, instead of `hdpi` ones.

Comment: As agamov pointed out in his answer below, the hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi rule is good to follow - the reason we have to use hdpi is that we support back to API level 9 (GB) which didn't recognise anything above hdpi.  Same reason we have xhdpi - to support OS levels which didn't recognise anything above that.  It'd have been great if the foresight to support up to xxxhdpi had been there to start with!

Comment: xxxhdpi seems an **overkill**, to me. I'm not aware of any real device using such a gorgeous density.

Comment: Assets file sizes aside (imagine how many pixels are in those xxxhdpi assets!), the point I was making is that it'd be nice to just have one set of drawables which magically scaled to the correct size.  But I agree, xxxhdpi is OTT.

Comment: I heard someone shouting **SVG** (or `VectorDrawables`, as a SVG sub-sub-subset which won't cost you an external free library, in LolliPop and later OS versions)!! Give them a hear, if you happen to.

Comment: It's the LP and later versions which is the killer here - that excludes the majority of Android users.  There are libraries out there to provide backward support for SVG drawables, but I've yet to investigate further.  It's certainly on my list of things to do though.

Comment: I'm successfully using `svg-android` (applantation version), for it's small size (about 30KB, if I remember well). I'm setting the size in code, basing on the retrieved screen density.

Comment: GIT: https://github.com/applantation/svg-android Also promising: https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/ This one is from our member Paul LeBeau

Comment: Paul does a great job in updating his library and friendly supports his users.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this nice article: http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/ from Cyril Mottier.

> The main point behind my hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi rule is simple. First, I cover more than 80% of my users. Secondly xxxhdpi exists just to make Android future-proof but the future is not now (even if it’s coming very quickly…). Finally I actually don’t care about the crappy/low-res densities such as mdpi or ldpi. No matter how hard I work on these densities, the result will look as horrible as letting Android scaling down the hdpi variant.

Although it doesn't directly answer your question, this might give you a bit of confidence that you're doing it right.